# LD_LIBRARY_PATH on Websphere Liberty profile not known anymore after redeployment JavaEE 8 EAR File

Tags: websphere-liberty, ear, java-ee-8

Hi I am currently facing a problem concerning the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable in Websphere liberty. The application server is used within a docker container and the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable is set within the server.env file. The first time, the container is starting, everything is fine. The ear is mounted into the container by directory and is getting started. The path within the Variable is resolved correctly.

While doing a rebuild of the ear, while the container is still running (for a shorter development turnaround) the application server detects the changes and restarts the new ear. But at his point, the LD_LIBRARY_PATH cannot be resolved anymore without any change in the server.env file.

Did anybody face the same problem yet and found a solution to it ?

If you need more information feel free to ask.

Comment: Do you fail to read the native envvar in your app, or do you fail to see its effect when you load a native library?

Comment: The second case you describe. It is said that the wanted .so file is not found in the library path on access.